# Google Places Autocomplete Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to integrate the Google Places Autocomplete API in my project but I am unable to achieve it with the documentation and also couldn't get some solid references for Swift-3. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You're saying you followed the instructions here?  They are written in Swift 3:
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions but that didn't help me. So was looking for some examples. And the libraries which are available are in Swift 2.

Comment: Hey, How did you implement it ? Can you please send link or demo ?
i also need to implement it and not sure which way to do
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Details

Swift 4, xCode 9

### Solution

Usual http request. More details: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

### Full sample

> PodFile

```
target 'stackoverflow-44996568' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'      
end
```

> GoogleAutocompleteJSONModel

```
import ObjectMapper

class GoogleAutocompleteJSONModel: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {

    public fileprivate(set) var placeId: String?
    public fileprivate(set) var reference: String?
    public fileprivate(set) var title: String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        title                       <- map["description"]
        placeId                     <- map["place_id"]
        reference                   <- map["reference"]
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(toJSON())"
    }
}
```

> Network

```
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class Network {

    class GoogleAPI {
        class Map {

            class var googleApiKey: String {
                return "YOUR_KEY"
            }

            class func autocomplete(request: String) {
                let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=\(request)&components=country:us&key=\(googleApiKey)"
                Alamofire.request(url)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                            //print("JSON: \(json)")
                            let places = Array<GoogleAutocompleteJSONModel>(json: json["predictions"])
                            let autocomplete = places.flatMap{ $0.title}
                            print("!!!! \(autocomplete)")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Extensions

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Element: Mappable {

    init(json: Any?) {
        self.init()

        var result = [Element]()
        if let array = json as? [[String: Any]] {
            for item in array {
                if let profile = Element(JSON: item) {
                    result.append(profile)
                }
            }
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```

> ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40)))
        searchBar.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(searchBar)
        self.searchBar = searchBar
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        Network.GoogleAPI.Map.autocomplete(request: searchText)
    }
}
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: Giving me two Errors in Extension
- Use of undeclared type 'Mappable'
- Non-nominal type 'Element' does not support explicit initialization
Please help me on this

Comment: Did you do "pod install" ?

Comment: Hi, could you please look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68394011/8894627

Answer (score 0):

You need to install google place SDK in your project through pods first.
`pod 'GooglePlacePicker'` you can use this code for install googlePlaces through pods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It had integrated it.

Answer (score 0):

I also created an simple library just to avoid various third party library and google framework for simple requests.

To make a Google api request like `Autocomplete`, `ReverseGeo`, `Place` info or `Draw` path you can simply use these steps :-

#### step-1 Import `GoogleApiHelper` into your project.

#### step-2 Initialise  `GoogleApiHelper`

```
GoogleApi.shared.initialiseWithKey("API_KEY")
```

#### step-3 Call the methods

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "San francisco"
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(input: input) { (response) in
    if let results = response.data as? [GApiResponse.Autocomplete], response.isValidFor(.autocomplete) {
        //Enjoy the Autocomplete Api
    } else { print(response.error ?? "ERROR") }
}
```

[You can find the library here](https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper)

[image]